# 9-bit serial communication with OS X

Tags: macos, serial-port

I need to receive 8S1 traffic using OS X computer, but space parity is not supported in OS X. I have read a few articles about CMSPAR-flag and about emulating 8S1 with even/odd parity such as this https://viereck.ch/linux-mark-space-parity/

Unfortunately CMSPAR is not defined and I can only receive the data, so the emulating is out of the question.

Is this the end of the story or are there ANY workarounds around this? I was desperate enough to try using even/odd parity and ignoring the parity bit completely by setting:

options.c_iflag |= IGNPAR;

...but for some reason or another, setting this didn't have any effect on the received data.

Comment: Linux has it's issues as well, however, it's possible to work around them. If you're able to compile `Qt` then something like this might work: https://github.com/JFF-Bohdan/ninebituart

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.